# Merging 2 strings

Tags: java

Hi I'm supposed to  write a program that takes two sentences from the user, The program then merges the sentence as shown:

> Enter sentence1: hello hope you are fine
>
> Enter sentence2: this is good
>
> hello this hope is you good are fine

I can only make use of String api to solve this code.

Currently my code returns the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1955)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter sentence 1: ");
        String sentence1 = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter sentence 2: ");
        String sentence2 = sc.nextLine();

        String combinedSentence = "";

        do {

            if (sentence1.indexOf(" ") > 0 && sentence2.indexOf(" ") > 0) {
                combinedSentence = combinedSentence + " " + sentence1.substring(0, sentence1.indexOf(" "));
                combinedSentence = combinedSentence + " " + sentence2.substring(0, sentence2.indexOf(" "));
            } else if (sentence1.indexOf(" ") < 0) {
                combinedSentence = combinedSentence + " " + sentence1;
                combinedSentence = combinedSentence + " " + sentence2.substring(0, sentence2.indexOf(" "));
            } else if (sentence2.indexOf(" ") < 0) {
                combinedSentence = combinedSentence + " " + sentence1.substring(0, sentence1.indexOf(" "));
                combinedSentence = combinedSentence + " " + sentence2;
            }

            sentence1 = sentence1.substring(sentence1.indexOf(" ") + 1);
            sentence2 = sentence2.substring(sentence2.indexOf(" ") + 1);

        } while (sentence1.isEmpty() != true && sentence2.isEmpty() != true);



    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: `indexOf` returns -1 when the string you are searching for is not found.

Comment: `sentence2.substring(0,sentence2.indexOf(" ") )` etc. - you might want to think about what happens if there is no more space.

Comment: Instead of messing with `indexOf(" ")`, you might find that using `split(" ")` makes the code significantly cleaner, as it will return you an array of the individual words for each sentence. It really depends how strictly you are sticking to the whole only using the String functions.

Comment: Another hint: there's also the `split` method ... ;)

Comment: A rough example of how using `split` might work is here: http://pastebin.com/umGbcL3T (not submitting as an answer, given the lack of clarity over whether this strays too far from only using String functions). If your unclear with the notation on lines 6 & 7, it's a compressed if statement, you can find more about them here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java .

Answer (score 0):

To make a program, divide it in little tasks:

- Divide `Strings` in `Arrays`
- Find Larger array
- Append one word from each `Array` until finish shortest
- get rest of other `String`
- append to result

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String SPACE = " ";

    // Divide strings in arrays
    String a = "hello hope you are fine";
    String b = "this is good";

    String[] aa = a.split(" ");
    String[] bb = b.split(" ");

    //Find Larger array
    int end = aa.length > bb.length ? bb.length : aa.length;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    //Append one word from each array until finish shortest
    for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
         sb.append(aa[i]);
         sb.append(SPACE);
         sb.append(bb[i]);
         sb.append(SPACE);
    }

     // get rest of other string
    String remaining = "";
    if (aa.length > bb.length) {
        // this oneliner is long, weird and uses Arrays library in purpose
        // it can be much more easy using String.substring and String.indexOf
        // YOU MUST MODIFY IT
        remaining = Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(aa, bb.length, aa.length)).replace(",", "");
    } else {
        remaining = Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(bb, aa.length, bb.length)).replace(",", "");
    }

    // append to result 
    sb.append(remaining.substring(1,remaining.length()-1));

    //when fixing the oneliner below will be just:
    sb.append(remaining);

    // output
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
hello this hope is you good are fine
```

Just replace the `String` definition by `Scanners`...